# How do you monitor your website?

Tags: monitoring

My team is responsible for a high traffic website, which is very dynamic with about 3.5 million unique urls. We deploy our application about 1 per week, we have a CMS that updates about 100 updates per week and our internal data source releases about 1 a week as well, and we consume about 10 other public webservices. It is always our teams responsibly to make sure everything is up and running.

We use pingdom to make sure some of are up, but it is limited to a few checks and it does not handle as many urls as we need.

We use Nagios as well but it is a bit of a black box and has not been fully adopted by our development team. Most of our developers are windows focused and cringe at the thought of all the configuration.

Most of what we need is just monitoring a few urls, and something that can notify me when things go down or change.

Comment: I voted to move this to serverfault, as it is not about programming.

Comment: Tools like nagios are very programmatic, and I always have to write programs to cover the short comings of the tools. I am not talking about server monitoring with tools like new relic. I am talking about making sure a large number services all work together properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should something like unit testing, that does internal testing of every website release before and after deoyment. Your application should have excellent exception handling as well and an exception should be logged and monitored.

If you use external monitoring with a tool like pingdom or [www.downnotifier.com](http://www.downnotifier.com) you can check one url per pagetime. For example: one news article, one text page and one product page.